# How do I set the computer to auto shutdown or standby / sleep after all downloads finish?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

The 'Auto Shutdown computer after all downloads finish' extension that I used for Firefox 3.6 - [Auto Shutdown 3.6.2D by InBasic](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/auto-shutdown/) , does not work with Firefox 4 or higher, even if I tweaked it to force its compatibility with versions of Firefox higher than 3.6.

Is there another extension, software, or solution that can automatically shutdown or standby / sleep the computer after all downloads have finished in Firefox 4 or later versions?

The OS I'm using is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

[Shutdown Timer](http://www.sinvise.net/home/projects/software/shutdown-timer). Set it to monitor download speed, works like a charm.

Comment: Just would like to add here that [Shutdown Timer](http://www.sinvise.net/software/shutdown-timer)'s network management functionality (monitoring of download speed)  is not free. You have to buy the 'Premium' version which has that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The **[Auto Shutdown NG](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-shutdown-ng/)** extension can auto shutdown or standby/sleep the computer after all downloads in Firefox finish.

Comment: The link is dead. :(